# Create flat object from values in deeply nested object with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating and returning this object with properties that originates in a deeply nested object:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  firstName: state.currentUser.obj.firstName,
  lastName: state.currentUser.obj.lastName,
  email: state.currentUser.obj.email,
})
```

Another way of doing it is like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {
    obj: {firstName, lastName, email},
  } = state.currentUser;

  return {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
  };
}
```

I'm pretty happy with the first example, but it would be nice to finde a way to skip the repetition of `state.currentUSer.obj` for every line.

Is there any conciser way to accomplish the above than the given examples?

**Input object:**

```
const state = {
  currentUser: {
    isUpdatingAccount: false,
    isUpdatingFavouriteColor: false,
    obj: {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null,
      favoriteColor: null,
      favoriteTeam: null,
    },
  },    
}
```

Comment: can you provide the input sample?

Comment: Use `const {firstName, lastName, email} = state.currentUser.obj;`

Comment: Are those three keys guaranteed to be the only ones that exist?

Comment: No, there could be more keys. See update in question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [nested destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring) to get the properties you want:

```js
const state = {
  currentUser: {
    isUpdatingAccount: false,
    isUpdatingFavouriteColor: false,
    obj: {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null,
      favoriteColor: null,
      favoriteTeam: null,
    },
  },    
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ currentUser: { obj: { firstName, lastName, email }}}) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email
})

console.log(mapStateToProps(state))
```

You should also add defaults as fallback to prevent errors in case parts of the structure are missing:

```js
const state = {
  currentUser: {
    isUpdatingAccount: false,
    isUpdatingFavouriteColor: false
    // I've removed obj as an example with default fallback
  },    
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ currentUser: { obj: { firstName, lastName, email } = {}} = {}}) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email
})

console.log(mapStateToProps(state))
```